# Check if varchar input is a valid date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that stores dates and whether they are a working day or not, including public holidays.

```
Date_Id     Date_Date   Date_JDE    Is_WorkingDay
20141223    2014-12-23  114357      1
20141224    2014-12-24  114358      1
20141225    2014-12-25  114359      0
20141226    2014-12-26  114360      0
20141227    2014-12-27  114361      0
20141228    2014-12-28  114362      0
20141229    2014-12-29  114363      1
```

I've created a stored proc that goes through the table and finds the date, and if the date is a non working day it finds the next that is.

```
DECLARE @TargetDate Date = '2014-12-29'

IF (@TargetDate IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM dbo.Dates
        WHERE Date_Date >= @TargetDate
        AND Date_Date <= (SELECT MIN(Date_Date) 
                            FROM dbo.Dates 
                            WHERE Is_WorkingDay != 0 AND Date_Date >= @TargetDate)
        ORDER BY Date_Date DESC

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN

        RAISERROR ('(TargetDate is required) is required ',10,1);
        RETURN

    END
```

How can i validate that the date is valid, so for example it is in a correct format and is a real date?

Comment: Do you think that "Select row then iterate until condition fulfilled" is appropriate to describe your requirement which actually seems to be: "How to check if a varchar is a valid datetime"?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Apologies, changed question title.

Comment: You can't trust that the dates in dbo.Dates are valid?  You don't own that table?   Can you build one that you do own and trust?

Comment: Have you tried `ISDATE(@TargetDate)`? Why don't you pass a `datetime` instead of varchar?

Comment: @TabAlleman: i assume OP wants to ensure that `@TargetDate` can be parsed to `datetime`.

Comment: Better yet stop using varchar to hold date information. Change the datatype to date and you can stop fooling around with trying to validate strings to dates.

Comment: I don't understand targetdate is already declared as a date, how can it contain invalid dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your script, try this instead:

```
DECLARE @TargetDate CHAR(10) = '2014-12-29'

IF @TargetDate is NULL 
   SELECT '(TargetDate is null)'
ELSE
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT MIN(Date_Date)
  FROM dbo.Dates
  WHERE 
    -- choose the format you need in convert. I used 126 which is isoformat
    Date_Date >= convert(datetime, @TargetDate, 126) AND
    Is_WorkingDay != 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT '(TargetDate is invalid)'
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the input format. 
use

```
SET DATEFORMAT format
```

& Cast your input to datetime/date inside a **try catch** block. Raise an error if it is invalid